# named entity extraction python script with flair framework stuck while training

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, named-entity-recognition

This is my code that I am trying to train in order to get a pretrained model for named entity extraction in french language . I am using google colab as an environment since my laptop has only 4GB GPU , whereas colab offers 12GB GPU . Sadly on colab , the script gets stuck in epoch 1 each time . can anyone suggest me a solution or a tip to solve my problem ? thanks a lot ! 
CODE :

```
from flair.visual.training_curves import Plotter
from flair.trainers import ModelTrainer
from flair.models import SequenceTagger
from flair.data import TaggedCorpus
from flair.data_fetcher import NLPTaskDataFetcher, NLPTask
from flair.embeddings import TokenEmbeddings, WordEmbeddings, 
StackedEmbeddings
from flair.embeddings import FlairEmbeddings, BertEmbeddings
from typing import List
from flair.data import Sentence 
# import flair.datasets
# 1. get the corpus
corpus = NLPTaskDataFetcher.load_corpus(NLPTask.WIKINER_FRENCH)
# 2. what tag do we want to predict?
tag_type = 'ner'
# 3. make the tag dictionary from the corpus
tag_dictionary = corpus.make_tag_dictionary(tag_type=tag_type)
print(tag_dictionary.idx2item)
# large embedding configuration - comment this in for a better model
embeddings = StackedEmbeddings(
   [WordEmbeddings('fr'),
   FlairEmbeddings('french-forward', use_cache=True),
   FlairEmbeddings('french-backward', use_cache=True)])
# 5. initialize sequence tagger

tagger: SequenceTagger = SequenceTagger(hidden_size=256,
                                    embeddings=embeddings,
                                    tag_dictionary=tag_dictionary,
                                    tag_type=tag_type,
                                    use_crf=True)
# # 6. initialize trainer

trainer: ModelTrainer = ModelTrainer(tagger, corpus)

# 7. start training
trainer.train('resources/taggers/example-ner',
          learning_rate=0.1,
          mini_batch_size=32,
          max_epochs=150)
```

Comment: CODE IS MISSING!

Comment: better to add code then image, so other can reproduce your error

Comment: any ideas on  how to overcome this problem ? or why does it fail to train properly on colab ? thanks

Comment: i don't know, not into ml/ai task for now, better to add `colab` tag so other can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can specify  **mini_batch_chunk_size** and **mini_batch_size** as shown below:

```
 trainer.train('resources/taggers/example-ner',
               learning_rate=0.1, 
               mini_batch_chunk_size=2,
               mini_batch_size=8,
               max_epochs=150)
```